# select and unselect from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

In multiselect jquery dropdown, I want if an item checked it gors to an array and if an item is unchecked it removes from that array. I did:

```
var optionValues = [];
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        optionValues.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('select option:not(:selected)').each(function() {
        itemtoRemove = $(this).val();
        optionValues.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, optionValues), 1);
    });
    $('#this').val(optionValues.join());
}).trigger( "change" );
```

```html
<input type="text" id="this">
```

but it shows nothing in the textbox. Any idea?

Comment: You're removing everything from the array in the second each loop, so it's always empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to use `map()` to create your array and to also create a brand new array on each change so you don't have to mess around finding a specific element of the array to remove. Try this:

```
var optionValues = [];
$('#myselect').change(function() {
    optionValues = $('option:selected', this).map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $('#this').val(optionValues.join());
}).trigger('change');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtuxeLk8/)

Comment: I want on unselect it remove from the array

Comment: This code does that. Check the fiddle for a demonstration.

Comment: That is great. Thank you very much! I will accept it after 8 mins

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you not checking for return of `$.inArray(itemtoRemove, optionValues)` call.

```
$('select option:not(:selected)').each(function() {
        itemtoRemove = $(this).val();
        var index = $.inArray(itemtoRemove, optionValues);
        if(index != -1) {
            optionValues.splice(index,1);
        }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/00shke8a/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
var optionValues = [];
$("select option:selected").each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).val());
  });

 $('#this').val(optionValues.join());
}).trigger( "change" );
```

http://jsbin.com/gejigucimo/1/edit